# How to control the refractive index of semiconductors?

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, refraction, optical-materials

I keep seeing/hearing that the refractive index can be controlled in semiconductors, but every time I read something like that it's always something very specific, like ["Refractive index dependence for GaAs"](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.328298) or even something like [carrier injection](https://doi.org/10.1109/JQE.1987.1073206) or [plasma dispersion effect](https://doi.org/10.1109/3.44924). But I keep failing to find a reference that lays down the fundamental principle that could be applied to any semiconductor, or junction. Can anyone recommend any reference?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure whether you’ll find exactly what you want since any mechanism affecting the interaction between light and a material will change it’s refractive index. As I understand it, the scope of the question includes arbitrary materials, arbitrary wavelength, and arbitrary physical mechanism. I’m afraid such a single resource doesn’t exist.

As an example of the breadth of this request, let’s just list a few ways refractive index can change based solely on a temperature change:

1. Thermal expansion/contraction changing the unit cell size
2. Carrier density change through thermal excitation (this is different for metals, semiconductors, etc.)
3. Phonon population change

These are all different physics and apply to different materials in different ways. And it’s non-exhaustive! That’s why you’ll only find specific references. Narrow your search!